# Dealing with dockers and containers in production

Tags: docker, containers, production-environment

I am new to the containers topic and would appreciate if this forum is the right place to ask this question.

I am learning dockers and containers and I now have some skills using the docker commands and dealing with containers. I understand that docker has two main parts, the docket client (docker.exe) and the docker server (dockerd.exe). Now in the development life both are installed on my local machine (I am manually installed them on windows server 2016) followed Nigel Poulton tutorial here https://app.pluralsight.com/course-player?clipId=f1f27565-e2bf-4e58-96f3-bc2c3b160ec9. Now when it comes to the real production life, then, how would I configure my docker client to communicate with a remote docker server. I tried to make some research on the internet but honestly could not find a simple answer for this question. I installed docker for desktop on my windows 10 machine and noticed that it created a hyper-v machine which might be Linux machine, my understanding is that this machine has the docker server that my docker client interacts with but do not understand how is this interaction gets done.

I would appreciate if I get some guidance or clear answer to my inquiries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production environments you never have a remote Docker daemon.  Generally you interact with Docker either through a dedicated orchestrator (Kubernetes, Docker Swarm, Nomad, AWS ECS), or through a general-purpose system automation tool (Chef, Ansible, Salt Stack), or if you must by directly ssh'ing to the system and running `docker` commands there.

Remote access to the Docker daemon is something of a security disaster.  If you can access the Docker daemon at all, you can edit any file on the host system as root, and pretty trivially take over the whole thing.  (Google "Docker cryptojacking" for some real-world examples.)  In principle you can secure it with mutual TLS, but this is a tricky setup.

The other important best practice is that Docker images should be self-contained.  Don't try to deploy a Docker image to production, and also separately copy your application code.  The same Ansible setup that can deploy a Docker container can also install Node directly on the target system, avoiding a layer; it's tricky to copy application code into a Kubernetes volume, especially when Kubernetes pods can restart outside your direct control.  Deploy (and test!) your images with all of the code `COPY`d in a Dockerfile, minimizing the use of bind mounts.

Comment: Thank you so much, that is what I need to know. I will start learning these topics, if you have any  article that simplify Docker Swarm, that would be appreciated. Thanks.